# C# ASP.NET Server Side Carousel Slider with Dynamic Number of Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working with a **server side carousel slider** and is having a hard time dealing with the manual scrolling of the slider. Although, automatic sliding is working using `data-interval="5000" data-ride="carousel"` of **bootstrap css and js.** I would like to know how to make the slides work just like in the client side scrolling. I managed to fetch data from the server but the slider controls  `<a href=""...next/> and prev` doesn't work.

Code:

**Slider.aspx**

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" 
           data-interval="5000" data-ride="carousel">                  
              <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>                  
              <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="carousel_inner" class="carousel-inner">                                           
              </asp:Panel>
               <%--- These won't work.---%>
              <a class="left carousel-control" runat="server" href="#myCarousel" 
                 role="button" data-slide="prev" style="text-decoration:none;"><</a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" runat="server" href="#myCarousel" 
                 role="button" data-slide="next" style="text-decoration:none;">></a>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Slider.aspx.cs**

```
//Sample data
int items = 8;

//Initial class
static string cssclass = "active item";
protected void ShowSlides()
{
    DataTable dt = SlideManager.GetSlidesDynamically(items);
    Literal str = new Literal();
    str.Visible = true;
    str.Text = "<br/>";
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Panel item = new Panel();
            item.Visible = true;
            item.CssClass = cssclass;            
            Literal img = new Literal();
            img.Visible = true;
            img.Text = "<img runat='server' " + 
                       "src='data:image/jpeg;base64," +
                        dr[0].ToString() + 
                       "' class='carouselImage' />";              
            item.Controls.Add(img);                
            Panel caption = new Panel();
            caption.Visible = true;
            caption.CssClass = "carousel-caption";
            Literal title = new Literal();
            title.Visible = true;
            title.Text = "<h3 runat='server'>" + dr[2].ToString() + "</h3>";
            Literal capt = new Literal();
            capt.Visible = true;
            capt.Text = "<p runat='server'>" + dr[3].ToString() + "</p>";
            caption.Controls.Add(title);
            caption.Controls.Add(capt);
            item.Controls.Add(caption);

            //Invoke all controls to slider
            carousel_inner.Controls.Add(item);
            cssclass = "item";    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure the id of carousel div  is `myCarousel`. In ASP the IDs get changed. If ID is not same then add this line `ClientIDMode=static` for carousel panel.

Comment: @JSantosh ClientIDMode=static worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: ohk posting is as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the id of carousel div is `myCarousel`. **In ASP the IDs get changed**. If ID is not same then add this line `ClientIDMode=static` for carousel panel